# Failed to use Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to use Apache RewriteRule to change the URL target page to abc.php. I have set RewriteEngine On but I found this problem.

Regexp I used:

```
RewriteRule ^viewthread\.php.tid=12345$ abc.php
```

The URL string to match:

```
viewthread.php?tid=12345
```

Why it is not successfully matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting URLs with query strings is slightly more complicated than rewriting plain URLs. You'll have to write something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/viewthread\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tid=12345$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.site/abc.php [R=302,L]
```

See those articles for more help:

- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/
- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

Answer (score 0):

i think because you have missed the ? in the rule...

```
RewriteRule ^viewthread.php?tid=12345$ abc.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
RewriteRule ^/viewthread\.php\?tid=12345$ /abc.php
```

Comment: Switch on logging and paste a snippet so we can figure out exactly what is going on